# splite value array ini php

Tags: php, arrays

i really need help about arrays. I have a case like this

```
[
   {"animal":"lion",  "car":"honda"}, 
   {"animal":"rabbit","car":"BMW"}, 
   {"animal":"rat",   "car":"Toyota"}, 
   {"animal":"mouse", "car":"Suzuki"}, 
   {"animal":"horse", "car":"mercedes"}, 
   {"animal":"dog",   "car":"Jaguar"}, 
   {"animal":"cat",   "car":"Audi"}
]
```

how in php code it can split become 2 category like this

```
$animal = [ "lion","rabbit","rat","mouse","horse","dog","cat"];
```

and

```
$car = ["honda","BMW","Toyota","Suzuki","mercedes","Jaguar","Audi"];
```

I really need to solve this. please help me

Comment: How do they end up like this in the first place?

Comment: That's not a php array. Is it a JSON string?

Comment: Look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Comment: Federico, yes it's a JSON string. Which is nice, it means we can actually have a play with the data, as opposed to pating a var_dump

Comment: because most devs don't need that explained, probably.

Comment: @delboy1978uk yeah, I deleted that condescending comment I wrote

Comment: no worries, have a good day :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) the string and use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to get the columns in each variable.

```
$json = '[
   {"animal":"lion",  "car":"honda"}, 
   {"animal":"rabbit","car":"BMW"}, 
   {"animal":"rat",   "car":"Toyota"}, 
   {"animal":"mouse", "car":"Suzuki"}, 
   {"animal":"horse", "car":"mercedes"}, 
   {"animal":"dog",   "car":"Jaguar"}, 
   {"animal":"cat",   "car":"Audi"}
]';

$arr = json_decode($json,1);

$animals = array_column($arr, "animal");
$cars =  array_column($arr, "car");

var_dump($cars, $animals);
```

https://3v4l.org/NtL9e

Answer (score 2):

Real easy. Decode the json, create two blank arrays, loop through, and add to each array:

```
<?php

$x = '[
   {"animal":"lion",  "car":"honda"}, 
   {"animal":"rabbit","car":"BMW"}, 
   {"animal":"rat",   "car":"Toyota"}, 
   {"animal":"mouse", "car":"Suzuki"}, 
   {"animal":"horse", "car":"mercedes"}, 
   {"animal":"dog",   "car":"Jaguar"}, 
   {"animal":"cat",   "car":"Audi"}
]';

$y = json_decode($x, true);

$animals = [];
$cars = [];

foreach ($y as $z) {
    $animals[] = $z['animal'];
    $cars[] = $z['car'];
}

var_dump($animals);
var_dump($cars);
```

https://3v4l.org/Fb7Bq

Answer (score 1):

try that:

```
  $arr=json_decode('[
   {"animal":"lion",  "car":"honda"},
   {"animal":"rabbit","car":"BMW"},
   {"animal":"rat",   "car":"Toyota"},
   {"animal":"mouse", "car":"Suzuki"},
   {"animal":"horse", "car":"mercedes"},
   {"animal":"dog",   "car":"Jaguar"},
   {"animal":"cat",   "car":"Audi"}
]');
var_dump($arr);echo'<br>';echo'<br>';
$animal=array();
$car=array();
foreach ($arr as $row){
    $animal[]=$row->animal;
    $car[]=$row->car;
}

var_dump($car);
var_dump($animal);
```

Comment: its work. in the output you have original table first an two tables witch animals and cars ..